# Использование классов из другого Namespace в asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

У меня приложение поделено на консольную часть и на web часть. Web часть использует классы из консольного проекта (Работа с бд). Но проблема какая когда я пытаюсь вывести объекты которые находятся в другом `namespace` выдает ошибку.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RSS' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Пробовал использовать `@using RSS` (Горит серым типа не используется). Только вот namespace  жизни не дает. Как можно подключить сторонний пространство имен в View проекта?

```
@model IEnumerable<RSS.App_Data.Item>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}    
<div class="row">
    @{
        foreach(var item in Model) {
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Source.name)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.title)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.date)
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Вот сам контроллер

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
        rssManager = new RSSManager();
        rssManager.AppInitialize();
        ViewBag.Sources = rssManager.GetSource();
        IEnumerable<RSSItem> items = rssManager.GetItems("ByDate", 0);
        return View(items);
    }
```

Comment: код покажите *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: какую часть когда показать? Вьюху?

Comment: ту, которую Вы считаете относящейся к вопросу

Comment: Добавил вью которая выдает ошибку

Comment: Очень хорошо. Еще код/namespace, где определен тип `RSS.App_Data.Item`, и как Вы вызываете `View` в контроллере.

Comment: Вы уверены, что добавили зависимость в веб-проект?

Comment: Контроллер добавил а RSS.App_Data.Item это сгенерированный код с помощью Linq to Sql ) Он сугобо громадный))

Comment: `IEnumerable<RSS.App_Data.Item>` и `IEnumerable<RSSItem>` - это разве одно и то же?

Comment: Тут не в выводе вопрос. матерится на то что он не видит сторонний namespace если бы проблема в выводе было вопросов бы не было. Я даже просто коментил все и все равно. Траблы

Comment: Тут я уже) эксперементирую методом тыка по этому могут оказаться странные виды) надписей)) я уже даже прописаывал в web.config сторонний namespace все равно не хочет подгружать его

Answer (score 1):

Вы указали неправильный тип модели во вью.

```
@model IEnumerable<[Full Namespace].RSSItem>
```

и

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.Source.name)
```

Comment: Неа )) Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'RSSItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) RSSNews E:\Documents\dotNetProjects\RSS\RSSNews\Views\Home\Index.cshtml 1 Active

Comment: С контролера все приходит проблем нет. Проблема вывода вот в чем проблемка. Именно не хочет вывод делать.

Comment: public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable <RSS.Classes.RSSItem >> {

Comment: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.Source.name)  Не правильно пишет

Comment: Если бы не данные которые надо получать из связанных таблиц  я бы юзал ViewBag притом с ним проблем нет вообще. А вот модели дурят голову